# Faster Way to Read File Line by Line?

Tags: php, mysql, fgets

In PHP, I use `fopen( )`, `fgets( )`, and `fclose( )` to read a file line by line. It works well. But I have a script (being run from the CLI) that has to process three hundred 5GB text files. That's approximately 3 billion `fgets( )`. So it works well enough but at this scale, tiny speed savings will add up extremely fast. So I'm wondering if there are any tricks to speed up the process?

The only potential thing I thought of was getting `fgets( )` to read more than one line at once. It doesn't look like it supports that, but I could in theory do lets say 20 consecutive `$line[] = fgets($file);` and then process the array. That's not quite the same thing as reading multiple lines in one command so it may not have any affect. But I know queue your mysql inserts and sending them as one giant insert (another trick I'm going to implement in this script after more testing and benchmarking) will save a lot of time.

**Update 4/13/19**
Here is the solution I went with. Originally I had a much more complicated method of slicing off the end of each read, but then I realized you can do it much simpler.

```
$index_file = fopen( path to file,"r" );
$chunk = "";
while ( !feof($index_file) )
    {
    $chunk .= fread($index_file,$read_length);
    $payload_lines = explode("\n",$chunk);

    if ( !feof($index_file) )
        { $chunk = array_pop($payload_lines); }

    }
```

Of course PHP has a function for everything. So I break every read into an array of lines, and `array_pop()` the last item in the array back to the beginning of the 'read buffer'. That last part is probably split, but not necessarily split. But either way, it goes back in and gets processed with the next loop (unless we're done with the file, then we don't pop it).

The only thing you have to watch out for here is if you have a line so long that a single read won't capture the whole thing. But know your data, that probably won't be a hassle. For me, I'm parsing a json-ish file, and I'm reading 128 KB at a time, so there are always many line breaks in my read.

Note: I settled on 128 KB by doing a million benchmarks and finding the size my server processes the absolute fastest. This parsing function will run 300 times so every second I save, saves me 5 minutes of total runtime.

Comment: You could try to read it "buffer by buffer" and put splited lines together again

Comment: Did you try to use fgetcsv function?

Comment: mmap or createfilemapping for php script will be helpful https://github.com/calcinai/php-mmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach that might be faster would be to read large chunks of the file in with `fread()`, split it by newlines and then process the lines. You'd have to take in account that the chunks may sever lines and you'd have to detect this and glue them back together.

Generally speaking the larger the chunk you can read in one go the faster your process should become. Within the limits of your available memory.

From [`fread()` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php):

> Note that fread() reads from the current position of the file pointer. Use ftell() to find the current position of the pointer and rewind() to rewind the pointer position.

Comment: How would I deal with split lines? I guess I could just save whatever comes after the last 'newline' in the rear, and glue it to the beginning of the next read. How do you tell fread( ) where to read from? Or like fgets, will it always auto-increment itself through the file as you keep calling it?

Comment: @l008com Yes. you'd need some variable to store whatever came after the last newline and combine it with whatever came before the first newline in the next chunk.

Comment: Better late than never. This side project has been put on hold but I did play around with doing reads exactly this way and it seemed to work very well. There was a speed boost from it, though not as fast a boost as I would have liked. Merging the database inserts really sped things up significantly.